# How to use user-defined Map in Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hashmap, mybatis

I've create a Class that implements Map. This will convert all the keys to Upper case and prevents duplicates

```
public class UCaseMap<T> implements Map<String, T> { }
```

Now, whenever I used it in Mybatis, it treats the class as POJO

```
<select id="selectQuestions" parameterType="map" resultType="com.quiz.utils.UCaseMap">
```

Here is the error message

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No obj found for 'QUESTION_ID' available keys []
### The error may exist in file [D:\Development\Workspace\QuizCreator\target\classes\com\quiz\mapper\impl\QuizMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.quiz.mapper.QuizMapper.selectQuestions
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: SELECT  QUESTION_ID, QUESTION, ANSWER_EXPLANATION,     CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY   FROM M_QUESTION   WHERE    DELETEFLAG = 0    AND CATEGORY = ?                       ORDER BY RANDOM()                  LIMIT ?
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No obj found for 'QUESTION_ID' available keys [], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@91161c7 testClass = TestQuizService, locations = '{classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null], method annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
```

do you know how mybatis treats that class as ordinary **map**? Like this one:

```
<select id="selectQuestions" parameterType="map" resultType="map">
```

Im using:

- mybatis 3.4.1
- mybatis-spring 1.3.0
- postgres 9.1-901-1.jdbc4
- spring 4.3.2
- java 8 and tomcat 8

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I tried the following custom map implementation:

```
public class CustomMap<T> extends HashMap<String, T>{

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        String uKey = key.toString().toUpperCase();
        return super.containsKey(uKey);
    }

    @Override
    public T put(String key, T value) {
        String uKey = key.toUpperCase();
        if ( containsKey(uKey)){
            return super.get(uKey);
        }else{
            return super.put(uKey, value);
        }

    }

}
```

And the following `select`

```
    <select id="getCountriesAsCustomMap" resultType="info.sanaulla.model.CustomMap">
        SELECT 
            c.code,
            c.name,
            c.continent,
            c.region
        FROM country c
    </select>
```

And I have a JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void test_getCountriesAsCustomMap(){
    List<Map<String, Object>> countries = countryService.getCountriesAsCustomMap();
    System.out.println(countries);
}
```

Which gives me the output:

```
{
  CODE=AFG, CONTINENT=clob2: 'Asia', 
  NAME=clob1: 'Afghanistan', REGION=clob3: 'Southern and Central Asia'
}
```

So custom map should work.